# how to parse the wsdl code in android

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

how to parse this xml code to get the  data shon on app:-

i am using eclipse for developing android app and i need to fetch data from magento through soap web service.

i am not understand how parse this please help me

and which is used here from xmlpull parser or jason parser?

```
     <definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soap=
      "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
                  "xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"                    
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Magento"   
           targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
       <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
     <!--
   <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
      schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
     -->
        <complexType name="FixedArray">
    <complexContent>
         <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
      <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
      </restriction>
      </complexContent>
     </complexType>
      </schema>
     </types>
    <message name="call">
       <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="resourcePath" type="xsd:string"/>
       <part name="args" type="xsd:anyType"/>
        </message>
         <message name="callResponse">
        <part name="callReturn" type="xsd:anyType"/>
        </message>
          <message name="multiCall">
       <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="calls" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
      <part name="options" type="xsd:anyType"/>
     </message>
       <message name="multiCallResponse">
     <part name="multiCallReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
      </message>
    <message name="endSession">
 <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
         </message>
       <message name="endSessionResponse">
       <part name="endSessionReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
       </message>
    <message name="login">
     <part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
            <part name="apiKey" type="xsd:string"/>
      </message>
      <message name="loginResponse">
    <part name="loginReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
     </message>
      <message name="resources">
      <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
          <message name="resourcesResponse">
       <part name="resourcesReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
       </message>
         <message name="globalFaults">
       <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
         </message>
         <message name="globalFaultsResponse">
       <part name="globalFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
        </message>
         <message name="resourceFaults">
      <part name="resourceName" type="xsd:string"/>
         <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
          </message>
        <message name="resourceFaultsResponse">
       <part name="resourceFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray"/>
         </message>
             <message name="startSession"/>
         <message name="startSessionResponse">
       <part name="startSessionReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
         </message>
         <portType name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
       <operation name="call">
     <documentation>Call api functionality</documentation>
         <input message="typens:call"/>
        <output message="typens:callResponse"/>
         </operation>
         <operation name="multiCall">
          <documentation>Multiple calls of resource functionality</documentation>
          <input message="typens:multiCall"/>
          <output message="typens:multiCallResponse"/>
        </operation>
           <operation name="endSession">
        <documentation>End web service session</documentation>
          <input message="typens:endSession"/>
        <output message="typens:endSessionResponse"/>
         </operation>
         <operation name="login">
       <documentation>Login user and retrive session id</documentation>
        <input message="typens:login"/>
          <output message="typens:loginResponse"/>
        </operation>
       <operation name="startSession">
       <documentation>Start web service session</documentation>
       <input message="typens:startSession"/>
         <output message="typens:startSessionResponse"/>
       </operation>
         <operation name="resources">
         <documentation>List of available resources</documentation>
        <input message="typens:resources"/>
       <output message="typens:resourcesResponse"/>
       </operation>
           <operation name="globalFaults">
         <documentation>List of resource faults</documentation>
   <input message="typens:globalFaults"/>
        <output message="typens:globalFaultsResponse"/>
      </operation>
        <operation name="resourceFaults">
       <documentation>List of global faults</documentation>
        <input message="typens:resourceFaults"/>
         <output message="typens:resourceFaultsResponse"/>
         </operation>
       </portType>
       <binding name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding" 
         type="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
      <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="call">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
       <input>
         <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"      
         encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </input>
        <output>
     <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
         encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
           </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="multiCall">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
        <input>
      <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"        
          encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
          </input>
       <output>
       <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"
        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>                        
         </output>
     </operation>
           <operation name="endSession">
             <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
       <input>
          <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
         encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </input>
        <output>
          <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"    
       encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </output>
           </operation>
          <operation name="login">
       <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
     <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
          encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </input>
       <output>
         <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </output>
    </operation>
     <operation name="startSession">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
     <input>
    <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
         encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
             encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </output>
     </operation>
    <operation name="resources">
       <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
    <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </input>
       <output>
       <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"  
             encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
       </output>
     </operation>
     <operation name="globalFaults">
             <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
         <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
               encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>                
          </input>
         <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         </output>
         </operation>
        <operation name="resourceFaults">
       <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"/>
       <input>
         <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" 
               encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                   </input>
              <output>
         <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded"                         
             encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
          </operation>
       </binding>
       <service name="MagentoService">
        <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort"                      
              binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://162.209.98.218/index.php/api/soap/index/"/>
         </port>
         </service>
         </definitions>
```